# How To delete Azure diagnostics in PAAS server after transferring data to azure blob

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

Facing problem with azure diagnostics(SDK Ver 2.6).

Problem Statement:

The diagnostic logs are stored into Azure blobs(final storage point), meanwhile  these log files are stored in below path in my PAAS VM.

C:\Resources\Directory\%RoleDeploymentID%.%RoleName%.LocalStorageName/LogFiles\Web\W3SVC1273337584

from here data is transferred to Azure blobs.
Since there is high utilization of website, log files are lined up in Local storage, crashing the site due to disk overflow(these logs are not getting deleted from local folder). I can't manually delete the logs from PAAS VM.

I use below config snippet in diagnostics.wadcfgx file

```
 <PerformanceCounters scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
<PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\Available MBytes" sampleRate="PT3M" />
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Web Service(_Total)\ISAPI Extension Requests/sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Web Service(_Total)\Bytes Total/Sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET Applications(__Total__)\Requests/Sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET Applications(__Total__)\Errors Total/Sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Requests Queued" sampleRate="PT3M" />
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Requests Rejected" sampleRate="PT3M" />
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" sampleRate="PT3M" />
    </PerformanceCounters>
```

Need help..

Comment: Can you share the settings for overall quota allocated for diagnostics? It should be something like `<DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration overallQuotaInMB="8192">` in your diagnostics.wadcfgx file.

Comment: <DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration overallQuotaInMB="4096">
        <DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Error" />
        <Logs scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Error" />
        <Directories scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
          <IISLogs containerName="wad-iis-logfiles" />
          <FailedRequestLogs containerName="wad-failedrequestlogs" />
        </Directories>
        <WindowsEventLog scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
          <DataSource name="Application!*" />
        </WindowsEventLog>

Comment: Particularly Worried about IIS logs in  C:\Resources\Directory\%RoleDeploymentID%.%RoleName%.LocalStorageName/LogFiles\Web\W3SVC1273337584  location.. These are huge and  causing disk Overflow(Site Slowdown).